# How to handle asynchronous methods properly in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-core-3.1

I am looking to retrieve a website response and send dots to the screen whilst doing so.

I am unable to do so using the code below. I'm sure I'm doing something rather silly, looking for any insights..

```
Console.Write("Doing Task...");
HttpClient web = new HttpClient();
Task<HttpResponseMessage> resp = web.GetAsync("http://localhost",
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
resp.RunSynchronously(); //Doesn't Work
resp.Start(); //Doesn't Work
while (resp.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
    Write.Operation(".");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
Console.Write("Done!");
```

Comment: _"**HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application.** Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."_ - [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) - but that's not your issue. Just a Heads-Up.

Comment: We would need a little more context. Is this code inside an async context or is it in `static void main` ?

Comment: To Verify: I don't want to await the task.. I want it to hit the while loop and send dots out to the console until it completes..
it is in a static void main method no async

Comment: RunSynchronously won't work, because that will wait on the task. I don't think you even need the .Start() - the task should start as soon as you get it... Maybe your task throws an exception instead of completes. Try doing Write.Operation(resp.Status) in the loop and see what the status is... it might go to Faulted or something instead of RanToCompletion

Comment: If I dont Start() it the resp.State stays at "WaitingForActivation"
If I do Start() it I get: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Start may not be called on a promise-style task.'

Comment: Yes, that's because the Task was not created by using one of its Ctors... I really think you need to use `Task.Run`.

Comment: When you call method with `"...Async"` suffix you get *already started* task back. No need to start it. But you need to `await` until it's finished typically (e.g. if you need `T` result from `Task<T>`). You can wait synchronously.

Comment: @Sinatr But he wants to do ouput while it is running. If it were to simply await it, I think he could figure it out.

Comment: @Fildor, I say *typically*. In OP case he can poll for task completition inside progress reporting loop.

Comment: @Sinatr but how does that fit into with _"If I dont Start() it the resp.State stays at "WaitingForActivation""_ ? Can't wrap my head around that, still.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Task.Run() just Task.RunSynchronously(); I dont know if this is a .NET Core 3.1 Issue

Comment: @xRavisher Yes, there is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1, but I am still not sure if you actually need it.

Comment: I see Run(); In the Object Explorer but no where else. It wont compile with Run(); and expects at least one parameter. Intellisense only shows RunSynchronously();

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1HhCJ4 - seems to work.

Comment: What happens if you put `http://localhost` in your browser?

Comment: Thank you @Fildor It does work! It appears my problem is the fact that my localhost takes forever to respond. And it sits in the "WaitingForActivation" state the whole time. It does start automatically and does get there in the end, but stays in that same state the whole time.

Comment: Thanks to you too @Milney you were right on the money from the start too!

Comment: @xRavisher the problem is you misunderstood tasks and treated them as threads. They aren't threads that need starting, they are *promises* that something will complete and produce a value in the future. Nothing more. Whether that something runs in the background or performs an asynchronous operation depends on the code that created that promise. `Task.Run` puts a job in a ThreadPool queue to be processed by a thread in that pool and returns a promise for its completion. `File.ReadAllAsync` on the other hand executes an asynchronous IO operation *without* using threads

Comment: @xRavisher neither of those promises needs a `.Start()` to start them, they are already active

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use async/await? Starting from C# 7.1 main method can be declared as async.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Task...");
        using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var resp = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost");
        var content = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are waiting for the **successful** execution of the `Task`, and this may never happen. You need to wait for its completion instead, whether successful or unsuccessful:

```
Console.Write("Doing Task...");
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var task = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost");
while (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    Console.Write(".");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
task.Wait(); // observe any exceptions that may have occured
Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

Alternatively you could use the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) overload that accepts a timeout. This is actually better because the completion of the task will be observed immediately, and not with a random 0-500 msec delay.

```
while (!task.Wait(500))
{
    Console.Write(".");
}
Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use async/await like the example below to capture any data returned from server in .NET Core:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var result = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost");
  Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
}
```